# Port not opening despite forwarded port, no firewall and an open listen server

Tags: networking, windows-10, port-forwarding, port

On my previous PC, I was perfectly able to open ports with no issues, however after a switch to a new PC, all ports refuse to open.

To illustrate the process I have used, I have done the same with the test port 1235.

1. [Forwarded port on router.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ99r.png)
2. [Created a listen server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYo7g.png) using [this tool](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/portlistener/)
3. Checked that the port is listening using `netstat -an`, where it reports a port listening at `0.0.0.0:1235`.
4. [Checked that the port is listening locally using PortQryUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do39h.png) , where it reports that TCP port 1235 is listening.
5. [Checked that the port is listening externally using PortQryUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21L73.png), where it reports that it is not listening.

To make sure that firewall is not the issue here, my firewall has been turned off and all third party firewalls have also been turned off.

I have searched around for a while, but I can't for the life of me find a solution that works for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** This happens for all ports, 1235 is just used to show the process.

Comment: Have you also changed the router when changing PC? Are you testing an internal port from an internal via the internet in a loopback from the same computer?

Comment: I'm still using the same router, and trying from another device/network does not change the result, however another device in the same network using the internal IP still works.